# Javascript onclick bject dependent method

Tags: javascript, object, methods, onclick

I got an image which toggles the onclick function. The function called is a method of an object.
My problem: i don't know the name of the object, so how can I

Initial HTML code:

```
<img id="someID" [...] onClick="someObject.aFunction();" />
```

Result wanted:

```
<img id="someID" [...] onClick="someObject.otherFunction();" />
```

My current Javascript (workaround):

```
someClass.prototype.aFunction() = function() {
    button = document.getElementByID('someID');
    button.setAttribute("onclick", button.getAttribute('onclick').split('.')[0]+'.otherFunction()');
}
```

Not very nice, but it works for the moment. Any better solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible solution:

```
var el = document.getElementById('someID');
el.onclick = function(){  
     // or some other prop
     if(el.hasBeenClicked)
         function1();
     else
         function2();

     // toggle the selected state
     el.hasBeenClicked= !el.hasBeenClicked;
}
```

Of course, there are many (better) solutions.
If you use jquery, than the code should be translated into something like :

```
$('#someID').toggle(function1, function2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
someObject.doFunction = function() {
    if (this.currentFunction == this.aFunction)
        this.currentFunction = this.otherFunction;
    else
        this.currentFunction = this.aFunction;
    this.currentFunction();
}

function h() { someObject.doFunction()}

var el = document.getElementById('someID');
if (el.attachEvent) {
    el.attachEvent("onclick", h);
} else {
    el.addEventListener("click", h, false); 
}
```